# Cisco 350 Series AP Not allowing DHCP

Tags: cisco, access-point

I am installing a Cisco 350 Series AP into an envirnoment that has 2 existing Cisco 350 Series AP's. The devices (MC9090) can connect to the AP but the device is not getting an IP address. The Error message on the MC9090 is that DHCP failed.

Is there a setting on the Cisco 350 Series AP that is stopping DHCP?

All three AP's are connected to the same switch on the same VLAN.

Answer (score 0):

What are the LED's on the box reporting? I believe there is  (1) Green & (1) Amber. Their state might give some insight on the current status of the AP.